# XCode 4 Cursor Jumps To First Line When Auto Suggesting

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, osx-lion

I have a problem in XCode 4.2 when I have the autosuggest feature turned on.  Whenever an autosuggest (autocomplete) pops up, the cursor will jump to the top of the file, to the second character of the first line.  This happens regardless of whether or not I select the autosuggest or take any other action.  As soon as I turn off the autosuggest feature, this behavior stops happening.

I have turned off all key binding associated with jumping to the top of the page and have deleted all derived data for the project as per some suggestions I have heard, but have not been able to solve the problem.

Anybody have a solution?

Comment: Did you remove the per-user settings files inside your project "file"?

- right click on your .xcodeproj file and select "Show Package Contents"
- remove `*.mode1v3`, `*.pbxuser` files and `xcuserdata` user data

HTH

Comment: You could also try removing your Xcode IDE preferences: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`

Comment: I did all of these and the problem persists.

Comment: maybe just reinstall Xcode (dev tools) but remove your /Developer folder first (or just move it aside)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem Xcode cursor jumped randomly. It was triggered by an editor theme using an italic font. I changed the font to a regular one, and the problem was resolved.

Simple solution (or workaround):

1. Open Preferences.
2. Open Fonts & Colors tab.
3. Select Basic theme.

I got the hint from [this page](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/2x30u3/xcode_editor_jumping_around_has_anyone_found_a_fix/).

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem  where the cursor jumped to the top and I couldn't scroll down. I don't know if it is the same problem that you have but there is no real solution. Its just one of Xcode's bugs there are a lot more. Open another file in the project and go back to the file you were working on, close and reopen the project or restart Xcode. Thats the only solutions I found.
If thats not working, then you can always re-install Xcode

Comment: I can scroll down just fine after it jumps up and get back to where I was working.  Also I have tried closing the file, project, application, and rebooting to no avail.

Comment: Then it seems like it is no temporary issue. I consider you reinstall xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there is a bounty awarded :) let me repeat my "solution" from above: I suggest moving aside your `/Developer` folder and re-installing Xcode. Simply running the installer w/o removing the old `/Developer` folder may not replace all the necessary files. Good luck.